# Fragments in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-manifest

com.google.android.gms.analytics.samples.mobileplayground has things like this in its AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".EventFragment"
        android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
```

Fragments in the manifest. That [used to be a no-no](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9391397/1034042), though it [is being done now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139488), apparently.
The Android docs are a vast maze of sometimes contradictory information, where can I get some reference (like [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)) - purpose, possibilities, limitations, etc?

[edit] Irritating that to disprove legit usage of Fragments in this way, we need someone of authority (google dev or someone very up-to-date on what they churn out), anyone else would just be guessing.

Comment: That is so weird. On the other hand, the analytics documentation (especially for v4) is patchy at best, so I'm not sure I believe that Fragments in the manifest is really a thing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a confusing thing the sample does.  It is technically invalid and accomplishes nothing as no part of the sample app tries to do a `startActivity()` for one of those and they are all non-exported because there's no `<intent-filter>` set for those entries.  If they did have an intent filter set for them or something tries to activate it via an explicit `Intent` it would fail because that class is not an `Activity`.  You cannot have a `Fragment` without a hosting `Activity`.

Comment: So just to be clear: Frags in Manifest is utter nonsense in general, or just here?
Maybe it's just a dirty trick to get [screenName tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/screens) to automatically work for Fragments?

Comment: That may be a little trickery the analytics auto screen tracking is using. I can't say for sure at this point.